# Unit could not be found - Init.d service

Tags: linux, boot

Holaa, lo que intento hacer es crear un daemon que esta alojado en `/etc/init.d/`,que ejecuta el archivo `servicio.sh` ubicado en `/bin`.

El dispositivo es una Raspberry con DEBIAN 10.

El problema viene cuando intento hacer `service servicio start` me sale el error:

`Failed to start servicio.service: Unit servicio.service not found.`

y si hago `/etc/init.d/serviciostart` no me sale nada.

Si hago `service servicio status` me sale:

`Unit servicio.service could not be found.`

**El código del daemon arranque es este:**

```
#! /bin/sh
 
NAME=servicio
DESC="Demonio del servicio servicio"
PIDFILE="/var/run/${NAME}.pid"
LOGFILE="/var/log/${NAME}.log"

#indico que voy ejecutar un archivo sh
DAEMON="/usr/bin/sh"
#Ruta del archivo
DAEMON_OPTS="/bin/servicio.sh"
 
START_OPTS="--start --background --make-pidfile --pidfile ${PIDFILE} --exec ${DAEMON} ${DAEMON_OPTS}"
STOP_OPTS="--stop --pidfile ${PIDFILE}"
 
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
 
set -e
 
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting ${DESC}: "
        start-stop-daemon $START_OPTS >> $LOGFILE
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
    stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon $STOP_OPTS
        echo "$NAME."
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        echo -n "Restarting $DESC: "
        start-stop-daemon $STOP_OPTS
        sleep 1
        start-stop-daemon $START_OPTS >> $LOGFILE
        echo "$NAME."
        ;;
    *)
        N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
        echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
 
exit 0
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se oye a que tu sistema usa SystemV, pero tu tratas de correr un servicio como si fuera el buen SysVinit.

Comment: eso quiere decir que tengo que crear me servicio para systemd?, si es asi , uan duda, systemd carga los scripst de init.d/ o del directorio de los scripts de systemd; esta pregunta es para saber si el sistema desde que arranca pasa por init.d y los carga :S , se que systemmd gestiona el init en mi pc acabo de comprobarlo pero donde estarian ubicados los servicios, hace falta poner el .service?

Comment: Si los carga, pero necesitas hace un hack por ahí con los comentarios. En unos segundos te paso un repo que hice para ver si medio te guía.

Comment: Este repo lo hice para que funcionara en ambos frameworks (SysV, Systemd) https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/systemd_start_gen, tu sólo dale permisos de ejecución a install service o lee el manual que hice con `man ./manual` dentro de la carpeta donde clones el repositorio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue hacer un servicio con systemd.

Para saber si tu sistema es systemd o systemVinit utiliza el comando `man init`